# Apache tomcat upgrade from version 7 to 9

Tags: tomcat

I am using an application (SysAid server free) that has Apache Tomcat version 7 bundled with the application.  Based on a recent vulnerability scan, I need to upgrade the version of Apache Tomcat. I downloaded the windows service installer from https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi.  I am not clear on how to verify the integrity of the downloaded files.  The links in the Release Integrity section lead to multiple more links and I have descended into a rabbit hole.

Is there a straightforward method to verify the file integrity (it is unclear to me how to do this correctly)?

Comment: Did you check the [Apache Software documentation](https://www.apache.org/info/verification.html)?

Comment: Is this a question about upgrading, or is this a question about verifying ASF package signatures?

Comment: Note that upgrading the version of Apache Tomcat used by this application may cause some problems. It might be better to get a newer version of the application with the latest bundled (and supported!) version of Apache Tomcat instead of trying to just swap-out the server version underneath the application.

Comment: Hi Christoper, Yes, this was both about upgrading and how to verify the package signatures to confirm they are authentic.  I agree it would be best to get a newer version of the application with the latest bundled and supported version of Apache Tomcat. Unfortunately, the application is the "free" version and they don't provide support unless you use the paid version. My company doesn't have a budget for this so I am trying to work around this obstacle by trying to do a swap out as you indicated underneath the application.   Is this really an option?

Comment: Hi Piotr, Yes, I did see that page but since I am new to Apache it is not making much sense to me. That is part of the problem.  Since we don't use Apache elsewhere in our environment I don't have the opportunity to did into this as one normally would, since I am just trying to resolve the main issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify file integrity in one of 2 ways:

1. Using the SHA-512 file hash

Download the compressed archive (e.g. `.tar.gz`) and also the file with the same name plus `.sha512`.

```
$ wget https://[mirror]/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.41/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz
$ wget https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.41/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz.sha512
```

(Note that the .sha256 file should always be downloaded from `downloads.apache.org` and never from a mirror).

Now check the hash. This is slightly different on different platforms.

Linux:

```
$ sha512sum -c apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz.sha512
apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz: OK
```

MacOS:

```
$ shasum -c apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz.sha512 
apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz: OK
```

I'm not sure the best way to do this on Windows.

You can also do either `sha512sum apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz` or `shasum -a 512 apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz` and then manually-compare the output to the contents of the file `apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz.sha512`.

2. Using the PGP signature

This is a little involved.

Download the compressed archive (e.g. `.tar.gz`) and also the file with the same name plus `.asc`.

```
$ wget https://[mirror]/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.41/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz
$ wget https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.41/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz.asc
```

(Note that the .asc file should always be downloaded from `downloads.apache.org` and never from a mirror).

Now verify the signature:

```
$ gpg --verify apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz.asc 
gpg: assuming signed data in 'apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz'
gpg: Signature made Thu Dec  3 06:48:37 2020 EST
gpg:                using RSA key A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7
gpg: Good signature from "Mark E D Thomas <markt@apache.org>" [undefined]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: A9C5 DF4D 22E9 9998 D987  5A51 10C0 1C5A 2F60 59E7
```

At this point, you can either go to a PGP key server and look-up the key fingerprint for Mark E D Thomas (`A9C5 DF4D 22E9 9998 D987  5A51 10C0 1C5A 2F60 59E7`) and check to see if he seems trustworthy. You'd make that determination by looking at who has signed his key.

The other option is to download the KEYS file from the Tomcat downloads page to be sure. The `KEYS` file only contains the PGP public keys of the Tomcat developers who are actually signing releases.

```
$ wget https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-9/KEYS
```

You have a few options, here. If you want to import all of these keys into your main GPG keyring, you can do this:

```
$ gpg --import < KEYS
```

If you don't want to add those keys to your keyring for some reason, you can build a temporary one:

```
$ gpg --import --no-default-keyring --primary-keyring ./apache-tomcat-keys < KEYS
```

Now you need to "trust" one or more of the keys. Unfortunately, you can't just say "trust everything in `./apache-tomcat-keys`" without a bit of editing.

Edit either your primary keyring:

```
$ gpg --edit-key A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7
```

or your temporary one:

```
$ gpg --edit-key --no-default-keyring --primary-keyring ./apache-tomcat-keys
```

Now assign trust to the key:

```
A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7
gpg (GnuPG/MacGPG2) 2.2.24; Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


pub  rsa4096/10C01C5A2F6059E7
     created: 2009-09-18  expires: never       usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: undefined
sub  rsa4096/A05557215E763BEC
     created: 2009-09-18  expires: never       usage: E   
[  undef ] (1). Mark E D Thomas <markt@apache.org>

gpg> trust
pub  rsa4096/10C01C5A2F6059E7
     created: 2009-09-18  expires: never       usage: SC  
     trust: unknown       validity: undefined
sub  rsa4096/A05557215E763BEC
     created: 2009-09-18  expires: never       usage: E   
[  undef ] (1). Mark E D Thomas <markt@apache.org>

Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision? 5
Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N) y

pub  rsa4096/10C01C5A2F6059E7
     created: 2009-09-18  expires: never       usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: undefined
sub  rsa4096/A05557215E763BEC
     created: 2009-09-18  expires: never       usage: E   
[  undef ] (1). Mark E D Thomas <markt@apache.org>
Please note that the shown key validity is not necessarily correct
unless you restart the program.

gpg> save
Key not changed so no update needed.
```

Finally, we are ready to verify. If you used your primary keyring, then:

```
$ gpg --verify apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz.asc
gpg: assuming signed data in 'apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz'
gpg: Signature made Thu Dec  3 06:48:37 2020 EST
gpg:                using RSA key A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: marginals needed: 3  completes needed: 1  trust model: pgp
gpg: depth: 0  valid:   3  signed:  52  trust: 0-, 0q, 0n, 0m, 0f, 3u
gpg: depth: 1  valid:  52  signed:  65  trust: 39-, 0q, 0n, 13m, 0f, 0u
gpg: [... info about trust db...]
gpg: Good signature from "Mark E D Thomas <markt@apache.org>" [ultimate]
```

If you used a temporary one:

```
$ gpg --verify --keyring ./apache-tomcat-keys apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz.asc 
gpg: assuming signed data in 'apache-tomcat-9.0.41.tar.gz'
gpg: Signature made Thu Dec  3 06:48:37 2020 EST
gpg:                using RSA key A9C5DF4D22E99998D9875A5110C01C5A2F6059E7
gpg: checking the trustdb
gpg: [... info about trust db...]
gpg: Good signature from "Mark E D Thomas <markt@apache.org>" [ultimate]
```

Ask about upgrading your Tomcat in a separate question.

Comment: Hi Christopher, Thanks. I see the wget commands but this is using Linux. Unfortunately I am using Windows and am not familiar with Linux. It just seems odd\a bit frustrating to me that download.apache.org is not considered a reputable site like downloads on the  Microsoft.com site.  There one can simply download the available without having to worry whether or not it is authentic.   I originally went to tomcat.apache.org to download  Tomcat 8.  So you are saying this is not a valid site?

Comment: Most downloads from X.apache.org go through "mirrors" because (a) ASF is a small organization and (b) there are huge numbers of downloads every day of ASF products. So, many ISPs, universities, etc. all over the world donate bandwidth to ASF by hosting the downloadable artifacts. Hosting those files means that they could theoretically be compromised by the entity hosting the download. This is why you *must* get the signatures from ASF and not from a mirror (because the mirror could theoretically modify the original, then generate a new signature).

Comment: There is no standard signature process for a ZIP file or tarball, so both PGP and SHA-512 hashes are provided. These are both *very* standard and not at all "not reputable".

Comment: The Windows binaries (`*.exe`) are all properly-signed and their signatures will be checked and verified by Windows when run as you would expect from e.g. files downloaded from microsoft.com. For the Windows installer, the process for verification is simply "run the installer".

Comment: I had completely forgotten about that (since I mostly use *NIX), and ASF still provides PGP and SHA-512 signatures for the Windows installer as well, "just in case". It's a good thing, too, since sometimes [Windows' verification isn't always reliable](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2020/01/patch-windows-10-and-server-now-because-certificate-validation-is-broken/).

Comment: Christopher,  Thank you.  I downloaded version tomcat 8.5.61 x64 zip from downloads.apache.org.  Sorry for what will be a foolish question but are you saying the contents are considered "verified" and not modified?  I know it is probably unlikely an option but could I swap out the contents of the tomcat 8.5.61 folders which include bin, conf, lib,logs,temp, webapps,and work and overwrite these folders on the server which has tomcat bundled with the application?

Comment: I would plan to backup the original tomcat folder to an alternate location.  As mentioned tomcat does not appear in Programs and Features but only appears to exist in the tomcat folder similar to the extracted folders noted above.  I would think it would not be possible to overwrite the original tomcat folder with the extracted ones above and expect the application to work. Is this correct?

Comment: If you use the ZIP distribution, you will have to verify the bundle manually as described in this answer (unless you just want to ignore trust and roll the dice on your mirror being trustworthy, which is entirely up to you). If you use the EXE, Windows verify if for you when you run it. Also, the EXE installer will "install" Tomcat so that you (a) can find it in Programs & Features and (b) get a Windows Service configured for you. You can manually-configure the service later if desired.

Comment: I would always recommend installing a new version of Tomcat into a new directory. Just migrate your existing configuration from the old one to the new one. *Take the time to read the migration guide(s)*. You can't simply copy your configuration from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 9 and expect it to work. Instead, start by editing the new `conf/server.xml` and comparing it to your previous one. The most important parts are usually the `<Connector>`s and any non-default-looking `<Host>`s.

Comment: If you'd like to discuss "upgrading" your bundled Tomcat installation, ask a separate question here on SO instead of abusing this existing one.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Sorry for the abuse.